# Measuring Apache Performance

Tags: performance, apache

As our servers gets busier I'm increasingly interesting in monitor what's going on over time, we have some our host offers some crappy graphs which show CPU usage and Memory over time but there not really telling me much.

What sort of high performance tools are available to accurately monitor Apache?

Comment: Sometimes administrative questions delve into command line pipes or shell scripting, however this is not at all programming related. Re-tagged as offtopic .. hopefully the SO sister site for general admin questions launches soon :)

Comment: You may need to write a program to interface with rrd (for instance, when not using cacti).  cron and a perl/php script — yes you can do it in bash but it's more difficult than the other ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup rrd to store data and create graphs based on data you send it.  I suggest parsing data from the apache logs and from the ps command.

You can also use the cacti package to create an interface to rrd.